# Default value of `server.servlet.session.persistent`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-session

How I see from the Spring Boot documentation the default value of `server.servlet.session.persistent` option is `false` but in my application it's `true` that's strange because I don't modify it explicitly. I guess Spring Security, or Spring Session, or Spring Redis integration turn it into `true`. May be someone here knows the root of this behaviour?

P.S. I use Spring Boot 2.1.5.

My pom XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.geekmarket</groupId>
    <artifactId>geek-market-ui</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>geek-market-ui</name>
    <description>Geek market e-commerce study project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/static/**/*.*</include>
                    <include>**/templates/**/*.*</include>
                    <include>**/db/**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/liquibase-maven-plugin.properties</propertyFile>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <user.name>aleks_usharovskii</user.name>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <logging>info</logging>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                        <version>3.24.0-GA</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                        <version>1.12</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Default values in Spring Boot https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: can you please share your pom.xml

Comment: Done. The whole project is here https://github.com/usharik/SpringBootPart2/blob/master/geek-market-ui

Answer (score 5):

The property `server.servlet.session.persistent` is `false` by default. However, it is overwritten by spring-devtools, which sets it to `true` (I think due to its restart/hot reload capabilities).

If you do not want session persistence, disable it directly in your `application.properties` file or in the properties file corresponding to your development profile.

You can check the source code on [Github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-devtools/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/devtools/env/DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor.java), there are multiple properties set in the Spring Environment by spring-devtools:

```
static {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("spring.thymeleaf.cache", "false");
    properties.put("spring.freemarker.cache", "false");
    properties.put("spring.groovy.template.cache", "false");
    properties.put("spring.mustache.cache", "false");
    properties.put("server.servlet.session.persistent", "true");
    properties.put("spring.h2.console.enabled", "true");
    properties.put("spring.resources.cache.period", "0");
    properties.put("spring.resources.chain.cache", "false");
    properties.put("spring.template.provider.cache", "false");
    properties.put("spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception", "true");
    properties.put("server.error.include-stacktrace", "ALWAYS");
    properties.put("server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.development", "true");
    properties.put("spring.reactor.debug", "true");
    PROPERTIES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(properties);
}
```